# How can I access the raw context of an IIB Message from a JavaCompute node

Tags: java, json, messagebroker

I'm trying to implement a JavaCompute node on an IIB 9 flow that will capture the text from the input JSON message and send it over the network to a 3rd party destination.

Looking at the message object structure, I can see a tree with all the elements of the json tree, but no obvious way to serialize that tree as a string.

Any pointers on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  I just figured out I need to call toBitStream